# Use subdirectory as root (or fake it)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wondering if there's a way to make a sub-directory (e.g. www.mysite.com/some_folder) act as root.

I'm assuming this would be something done on the `.htaccess` file but I can't find anything helpful.

The PHP application running uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which is naturally going back to www.mysite.com/ but I need it to use the /some_folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're running apache, you can find the document root property in the configuration file located in:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

for most linux installs.

For windows, you'd have to search google for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overwriting the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/some_directory';
```

Just do that at the top of your script, it's a bit hacky but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess, you can rewrite the user queries or redirect, but the user will still see the sub directory (in their address bar, or whatever).

You can have a sub directory point to root by creating a sub directory that is just a link to the root folder. However, you can't go the other way.

There may be other solutions, but they'll most likely involve modifying the document root on the server.